# Get a variable after ajax done

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code for make some request to my server:

```
function myAjaxCheck(token) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'auth.php',
            data: {
                token: token,
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.auth == 'OK') {
                    alert ('ok');
                    }
                } else {
                    alert('Error: ' + data.auth);
                }
            }
        }).done(function (data) {
            return data;
        });
    }
```

So, i need to pass the returned data into a variable like:

```
Var MyVariable = myAjaxCheck(token);
console.log(MyVariable);
```

### at console:

### undefined

Where is the problem, is supposed to data will returned when done, but isn't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, an `ajax()` request is asynchronous so the call to `ajax()` will usually return before the request completes. You could make use of a callback function instead.

```
function myAjaxCheck(token, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'auth.php',
            data: {
                token: token,
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.auth == 'OK') {
                    alert ('ok');
                    }
                } else {
                    alert('Error: ' + data.auth);
                }

                callback(data);
            }
        });
    }

var myVariable; 
 myAajxCheck(token, function(returnedData){ //anonymous callback function
    myVariable = returnedData;
    console.log(myVariable);
 });
```

If you absolutely must, you could use [`async: false` inside the call to `ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

Please see [Waiting for $.post to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230964/waiting-for-post-to-finish/6230996#6230996).

Basically, it is better to **use callbacks**. Your variable seems to be `undefined`, because the code returning it to the console **is executed before the AJAX request is finished**.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are expecting a value to be returned immediately. You are using asynchronous XHR, so, the function will return (`undefined` in this case) before the XHR has a chance to finish and return its value.

Comment: Ok, but what is the solution? Please add more to your answer to make it better